# Python basics why set() works but {} fails?

Tags: python, list, set, curly-braces

```
s = ["this", "that", "this"]
```

Why does `set(s)` work but `{s}` fails with

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: '{}' is for a dictionary and expects a key as first entry. A list is not a valid key. exanple '{ 1 : s }' will work.

Comment: No when used on singular entity it's for a set. I am asking for {x} not {'x':'y'}

Comment: Was not aware of that syntax for a set. You never stop learning. :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because they mean different things.  `set(s)` iterates `s` to create a set, whereas the literal syntax `{s}` just attempts to create a set containing the single element `s`.

```
>>> set("abc")
{'a', 'b', 'c'}
>>> {"abc"}
{'abc'}
```

Try `{*s}` instead for the equivalent of `set(s)`.

Comment: so set(x) is more than just {x}.

Comment: @Coddy Not necessarily - when `x == ""`, then `set(x)` is less than `{x}`