# Difference between list() and creating a list through []

Tags: python, list, function, methods, attributes

Whats the difference between creating a list through a method like

```
x= list('')
```

and this

```
x = ['']
```

Here is the code if I use list [] to make a list it will think every letter is wrong but if I use list() it works perfectly fine

```
    mainword = input("Enter your word").lower()
    builtword = ''
    number = list(mainword)
   
    correctLetters = list(number)
    buildword2 = ['']

    userGuess = input("Guess letter").lower()
    print(userGuess)

    while builtword != mainword:
    if userGuess in correctLetters:

    print('That was correct')
    x = number.find(userGuess)
    print(x)

    builtword = builtword+userGuess.lower()
    print(builtword)
    if builtword != mainword:
        userGuess = input("Guess letter").lower()

else:
    print('sorry that\'s wrong try again')
    userGuess = input("Guess letter").lower()

print("Congratulations you finished the word was "+mainword.capitalize())'''
```

Comment: `[]` is faster and more idiomatic. Bytecode is different. Only use `list()` for conversions. Difference can be seen by `dis`: `dis.dis('[]')` and `dis.dis('list()')`.

Comment: This is similar to [Python basics why set() works but {} fails?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65836354/674039)

Answer (score 2):

The two expressions are not equivalent.

`list('')` iterates over each character of the string, turning an empty string into an empty list:

```
>>> list('')
[]
```

`['']` creates a list containing a single, empty string.

```
>>> ['']
['']
```

If the string is not empty, it's a bit easier to see the effect:

```
>>> list('123')
['1', '2', '3']
>>> ['123']
['123']
```

Comment: How would I find a specific thing in the first example, like for example I wanted to find which space 2 was in since .find() does not work.

Comment: You could try the [`index` method](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) of `list`.